# Append к классу

Tags: jquery

Не применяется .append для классов. Вот код:

html:

```
<div class="products"></div>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "product.php",
    success: function (product) {
        $('.products').append(product);
    }
})
```

В данном случае код не работает, но если поменять на `id="products"` и `$('#products')` то все будет работать как нужно. В чем проблема, понять не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var product = "<b>TEST</b>";
$('.products').append(product);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">One </div>
<div clаss="products">Two </div>
<div class="products">Three </div>
```

Comment: В вашем случае добавление выполнилось. Тогда в чем дело? В php?

Comment: @Malyuga Обратите внимание на букву "а" в названии атрибута `class` во втором диве. Она из кириллицы.

Comment: Да, я увидел это. Ошибку я тоже устранил, я просто пропустил `;`. Спасибо за ответ!